# Prevent apache rewriting URLs

Tags: docker, apache2

I'm trying to migrate a site over to Docker. I've followed a number of guides and I'm almost there.

I'm using the php:7.2.7-fpm-alpine3.7 image to separate PHP from Apache.

My site is in the local folder /var/www/html/app with the Apache Docker container.

My Apache conf file looks like this:

ServerName localhost

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.(php|inc)(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
</VirtualHost>
```

My issue is that Apache appears to be rewriting/editing the URLs at some point and I can't figure out why, for example if I try to access a file at http://localhost/app/htdocs/install.php I will see logs for GET requests to /app/dist/* (the location should be /app/htdocs/dist/* and thus I get a 404). Install should lead to http://localhost/app/htdocs/admin/install_db.php but instead the browser goes to http://localhost/app/admin/install_db.php.

I believe this is a rewrite issue because the same site code on the host machine with a standard *AMP stack works without issue.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue with a separate situation specific config file I had not taken into account.